# Determine if number is a prime number

Tags: python, beginner, primes

I made a function that takes an argument `x` and returns `True` if `x` is a prime number and `False` if `x` is a non-prime number.

I am a beginner and think the code can be improved. I had to add the else statement because for `is_prime(2)`, I kept getting `None` instead of `True`. I think this was because when `x` is `2`, `list_n = range(2,2)` prints `[]`.

Are there ways I could change this so there is not a separate else statement?

```
def is_prime(x):
    list_n = range(2,x)

    if x <= 1:
        return False
    elif x-1>2:
        for n in range(len(list_n)):
            list_n[n] = x % list_n[n]
        for n in list_n:
            if n == 0:
                return False
        for n in list_n:
            if n > 0:
                return True
    else:
        return True
```

Answer (score 13):

To begin with, you don't need `list_n` at all: a decision that the number is composite can be made on the fly, as soon as some remainder becomes 0. If none of them were 0, you know that the number is prime:

```
    for n in range(2, x):
        if x % n == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

is effectively what your code is doing, but without the list, and without special case for `2`.

That said, of course the algorithm could be greatly improved, but it is beyond the point of this exercise.

Comment: Don't forget the edge case `n <= 1`, which was handled in original code.

Comment: n.b. that `for n in range(2, x)` checks more numbers than necessary to see if `x` is prime. The greatest unique divisor of `x` (that isn't a co-divisor of a smaller number, e.g. 32 => (**2**, 16)) is `sqrt(x)`. `for n in range(2, int(x ** 0.5)+1)` is sufficient to test for primality.

Comment: @AdamSmith Yes, this is what the last line in my post is about.

Comment: @vnp Ah. I assumed you were talking about using a Sieve or etc

Answer (score 7):

1. You don't need to create a list. Just iterate over potential divisors:
   `for d in xrange(2, x): ...`
2. The condition `x - 1 > 2` seems kind of complicated. I suggest adding a guard at the beginning of the function:

   ```
   if n <= 1:
       return False
   ```

   and using a generic procedure for all other numbers (including 2. It works for `x = 2`. There's nothing special about it). It'll make your code easier to follow.
3. You can make it more efficient by checking the divisors only up to `sqrt(x)` inclusively. If a number is not a prime, it must have at least one divisor not greater then its root.

Comment: Your first point depends on whether he's using Python 2 or Python 3. Python 3 has no `xrange`, since it's `range` already behaves as such.

Comment: @Mast He must be using python 2. Otherwise, `list_n[n] = ...` won't work (range doesn't support assignment in python 3) and his code is broken for any `x >= 3`.

Comment: I'm so accustomed to Python 2 I didn't even catch that would break on 3. Good call.

Answer (score 6):

1. Use a better variable name than `x`.
2. Add separate `if`-clauses to check if your input number is `<= 1`, `== 2` and `% 2 == 0`.
3. Beyond the above exclusions, you only have to deal with odd numbers. Check only against odd divisors: `xrange(3, sqrt(your_input), 2)`.
4. This loop is entirely useless:

   ```
   for n in list_n:
       if n > 0:
           return True
   ```

---

You'll end up with something like

```
def is_prime(integer):
    """Returns True if input is a prime number"""
    if integer < 2 or not isinstance(integer, (int, long)):  # remove long if using Python 3
        return False
    if integer == 2:
        return True
    if integer % 2 == 0: # which can also be written as -> if not integer & 1:
        return False
    for divisor in xrange(3, int(math.sqrt(integer)) + 1, 2):
        if integer % divisor == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: I must say I disagree with this. Calling a variable ```x``` where it is clear that this is an abstract variable (yes, an integer) is much more useful than calling it ```integer```. If you see a function called ```add(a, b)``` isn't it obvious what ```a``` and ```b``` do?

Comment: @Coal_ yes, but nearly all pep8 based linters will report that as an invalid argument name.

Comment: @hjpotter92 then fix the linter. single-letter variable names are made for instances like this, and PEP8 does not declare against them. Sounds like an overreach of the linter.

Answer (score 4):

The third `for` loop can be replaced with a single `return True` statement (because it's the exact opposite of the second `for`). Also, the `else:` can be removed as if any previous conditions were satisfied, the function would have already returned. The `return True` block formerly in the `else:` block can be fused with the third `for` loop's `return`, producing this code:

```
def is_prime(x):
    list_n = range(2,x)

    if x <= 1:
        return False
    elif x-1 > 2:
        for n in range(len(list_n)):
            list_n[n] = x % list_n[n]
        for n in list_n:
            if n == 0:
                return False
    return True
```

Another suggestion is to replace the first `for` with a list comprehension. This is left as an exercise to the reader.

Answer (score 3):

Just remove `else:` and unindent `return True`. That should work since `if` and `elif` will always return if entered.